# HTML Color-picker with colors box

Tags: jquery, html

I'm setting up the HTML code and I want to display the list of colors in the HTML which it shows like this:

[image]

If I want to create the list of colors, I would need to create a table and list of div blocks with colors like this:

```html
<table style="user-select: none;">
  <tbody style="user-select: none;">
    <td style="user-select: none;">Background colour</td>
    <div title="RGB (0, 0, 0)" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); user-select: none;"></div>
    <div title="RGB (68, 68, 68)" style="background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68); user-select: none;"></div>
    <div title="RGB (102, 102, 102)" style="background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102); user-select: none;"></div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'd find that it is alot of work to do and I might not need to do this. I've tried to find on google to search for what I'm looking for, but I'm unable to find it so I need your help.

If I want to create the list of colors in the html, do I have to create a table with list of div blocks with colors or if there is a way to create a short HTML code to make it much shorter, easier and quicker so I could display the background-colors and text-colors exactly like what the screenshot are showing?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no jQuery in your question. Easiest would be to define the colours as an array in PHP (for example) or JavaScript and then have that language output the HTML via a loop, rather than laboriously doing it manually.

Comment: @Utkanos Yeah there is no jquery in my question, but I want to use jquery to pick the color I want when I click on a button. So can you please show me an example how I could define the colors as an array in javascript so I could output them in the HTML?

Comment: Well here are the steps: 1) in your JS, define an array of colours. If you're unsure how to create an array in JS, check MDN or a tutorial. 2) Loop over that array and output the colours to your HTML somewhere, e.g. to a list element. Again, if you're unsure how to create elements via JS, check MDN for `createElement()`.

Comment: @Utkanos ok thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I would suggest finding a color picker already written as a faster/easier path to results - if you are using this as a learning tool, that is another matter then.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I cant *comment* this "solution" just yet. This is NOT an optimal solution, but you can try this in case nothing you tried worked:

```html
<input id="color" type="color" onchange="submitValue(this.value);" value="#ffffff" placeholder="#000000">
```

You can then pass the choosen color to another function, in this case, to the function "submitValue();"

I hope this helps!